# Why do two images of same ImageDimensions display very differently in notebook?

Tags: image-processing, notebooks

I've downloaded two images from the internet.  They are identical sizes, yet they are displayed quite differently in the notebook.

Why?

Here's the example:

```
imgUrls = List["https://cards.scryfall.io/normal/front/0/0/0031d026-9e9a-46f6-8204-1acfee8b8809.jpg?1561894880","https://cards.scryfall.io/normal/front/0/0/00bbaefd-e7dc-4870-ad9c-e94e27de3860.jpg?1551119690"}];
imgs = Map[Import, imgUrls]
```

[image]

```
Map[ImageDimensions, imgs]
```

{{488,680},{488,680}}

In case it matters, there is no MetaInformation associated with these images.

Comment: Download both images and take a look at [their metadata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbCmY.png) (EXIF). One of them has resolution 96 dpi and the other 300 dpi. Mathematica takes this into account and appropriately scales the output.

Comment: You can also see this with ``Information /@ imgs``. One of them has Image Resolution {300, 300}, and the other Automatic.

Comment: @Domen, makes sense.  What is particularly confusing about this is that the physical objects that these are scans of are the same size, so the DPI information is off.  I hadn't realized that "Information" was different from "MetaInformation."  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check properties of images by:

```
Information /@ imgs
Options[#, ImageResolution] & /@ imgs
```

Or if you want them to be displayed with the same resolution use this:

```
Image[#, ImageResolution -> Automatic] & /@ imgs
```